# github API using ocotokit: cannot create/update file for personal repos (no organization)

Tags: api, github, octokit

I created a github app. when user authorize the app I can access his **organizations** repos: list repo, branches, create and update files.

when the repos are not organization repos, (regular repos), I can list the repos and get files content BUT cannot create or update files.

application asks full permissions to all (read-write or admin)

the error I get is:
Resource not accessible by integration

```html
     it('octokit create ', async (done) => {
    
         const octokit = new require('@octokit/rest')({
             debug: true
         })
    
         let a = await octokit.authenticate({
             type: 'app',
             token: 'myToken'
         })
         console.log (a)
    
       let b =  await  octokit.repos.createFile({
             owner: 'owner',
             repo: 'test',
             path: 'path/tyty435.txt',
             message: 'blahc blahc',
             content: 'YmxlZXAgYmxvb3A=', 
             branch: 'master'
         })
    
    
    
         console.log (b)
     })
```

Thanks,
Amos

Comment: when creating a token manually in the WEB, all is working fine. only with the github app token it is not working

Comment: Is it the same github app? What permission did you grant it?

Comment: maximum permissions, read-write or admin when possible

Comment: sounds like an API issue, I would suggest to contact support@github.com